# UIButton I need to create a button with curved edges and borders but I'm not sure how to do it

Tags: uibutton

I have been searching all over google trying to find an answer to this but can't.  I need to create a buttin that has rounded or curved edges as well as adding a border to it.  Nothing I yhave tried has worked.  please help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest showing us what you have already tried; that said, here is what I use:

```
@IBDesignable class MyButton: UIButton
{
    @IBInspectable var borderColor:UIColor? {
        set {
            layer.borderColor = newValue!.cgColor
        }
        get {
            if let color = layer.borderColor {
                return UIColor(cgColor:color)
            }
            else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
    @IBInspectable var borderWidth:CGFloat {
        set {
            layer.borderWidth = newValue
        }
        get {
            return layer.borderWidth
        }
    }
    
    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        
        updateCornerRadius()
    }
    
    @IBInspectable var rounded: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            updateCornerRadius()
        }
    }
    
    func updateCornerRadius() {
        layer.cornerRadius = rounded ? frame.size.height / 2 : 0
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated!